# Freertos and the necessity of uart transmit interrupt

Tags: interrupt, uart, freertos

For uart reception, it's pretty obvious to me what can go wrong in case of 'blocking receive' over uart. Even in freertos with a dedicated task to read from uart, context / task switching could result in missing bytes that were received in the uart peripheral.

But for transmission I am not really sure if there is a need for interrupt based approach. I transmit from a task, and in my design it's no problem if that task is blocked for a short while. (it also blocks/sleeps on mutexes e.g).

Is there another strong argument to use use uart transmit in interrupt mode? I am not risking anything wrt loss of data, right?

In my case I use an stm32, but I guess the type of mcu is not really relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's focus on TX only and assume that we don't use interrupts and handle all the transmission with the tools provided by the RTOS.

µC UART hardware generally have a transmit shift register (TSR) and some kind of data register (DR). The software loads the DR, and if the TSR is empty, DR is instantly transferred into TSR and TX begins. The software is free to load another byte into DR, and the hardware loads the new byte from DR to TSR whenever the TX (shift-out) of the previous byte finishes. Hardware provides status bits for querying the status of DR & TSR. This way, the software can using polling method and still achieve continuous transmission with no gaps between the bytes.

I'm not sure if the hardware configuration I described above holds for every µC. I have experience with 8 & 16-bit PICs and STM32 F0, F1, F4 series. They are all similar. UART hardware doesn't provide additional hardware buffers.

Now, back to RTOS... Obviously, your TX task needs to be polling UART status bits. If we assume that UART baud rate is 115200 (which is a common value), you waste ~90 µs of polling for each byte. The general rule of RTOS is that if you are waiting for something to happen, your task needs to be blocked so other tasks can run. But block on what? What will tell you when to unblock? For this you need interrupts. Your task blocks on *task notification*, (`ulTaskNotifyTake()`), and the interrupt gives the notification using `xTaskNotifyGive()`.

So, I can't imagine any other way without using interrupts. **But, the method mentioned above isn't good either.** It makes no sense to block - unblock with each byte.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Move TX handling completely to interrupt handler (ISR), and notify the task when TX is completed.
2. **Use DMA instead!** Almost all modern 32-bit µCs have DMA support. DMA generates a single interrupt when the TX is completed. You can notify the task from the DMA transfer complete interrupt.

On this answer I've focused on TX, but using DMA is the proper way of handling reception (RX) too.

Comment: I have read about DMA before and I guess avoided it because it scared me away. I will dive into this if this really is the proper way of doing so. Thx for the perfect explanation on tx, this really helps!